# Configuration subversion tags to work with modules

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, module

How can I configure Subversion in IntelliJ IDEA to support multiple modules? Each module has it's own trunk, tags and branches folders, but all modules are checkouted from one reposiotry. Structure of my repository looks like that:

```
/my_project
  /folder1
    /module1
      /trunk
         .... all module files
      /tags
         /1.0
         /2.0
      /branches
         /b1
    /module2
      /trunk
         .... all module files
      /tags
         /1.0
         /2.0
      /branches
  /folder2
    /module3
      /trunk
         .... all module files
      /tags
         /1.0
         /2.0
      /branches
  /module4
    /trunk
       .... all module files
    /tags
       /1.0
       /2.0
    /branches
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just go in to `Settings` -> `Project Settings` -> `Version Control` and on the right side you should see a table for Version Control directory mappings like this:

[image: Version Control Directory mappings]

You can use the `+` button to define different source roots corresponding to different directories in your project.

Of course the alternative is to use multiple projects instead of one mega-project, but that involves a lot of alt-tabbing and I'm sure you've considered this alternative already.

Anyway, this (plus some use of right-click: `Subversion` -> `Relocate`... to select the correct source roots for each module) solved a similar issue for me in the past - does it work for you?